# Android ShapeDrawable stroke is blurred

Tags: android, shapedrawable

I created a rather simple shapedrawable with semi-transparent borders, and used it as a background for two adjacent view.

Either if the srtoke color is partially transparent, I'm expecting a solid stroke (like the image on the right), but what I get is a blurred stroke (image on the left).

What I'm doing wrong?

[image: actual vs expected]

(images are taken from the ADT preview, in the emulator the effect is even more visible)

This is the ShapeDrawable (`theme_base_bg_framed.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/base_frame_solid_color"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/frame_border_size"
        android:color="@color/base_frame_border_color"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="@dimen/frame_padding_size"
        android:top="@dimen/frame_padding_size"
        android:right="@dimen/frame_padding_size"
        android:bottom="@dimen/frame_padding_size"
        />
</shape>
```

It uses these color and dimen definitions:

```
<color name="base_frame_solid_color">#20ffffff</color>
<color name="base_frame_border_color">#40ffffff</color>

<dimen name="frame_border_size">2dp</dimen>
<dimen name="frame_padding_size">2dp</dimen>
```

Both drawables are assigned to the `View`s background

```
<style name="ViewWithBorder">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/theme_base_bg_framed</item>
</style>
```

Edit:

The colors used in the ShapeDrawable are alphaed for a reason. The view in the background is going to contain other views and/or images. This is a better example of what I get (left) and what I'm expecting to get (right).

[image]

Comment: Remove padding and try again

Comment: @Gunaseelan: same result

Comment: @FrankN.Stein: I mean "sharp" stroke with semi transparent color

Answer (score 1):

I use this values to get the result you wanted:
colors.xml:

```
<color name="base_frame_solid_color">#20000000</color>
<color name="base_frame_border_color">#40ffffff</color>
```

shape:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/base_frame_solid_color"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/frame_border_size"
        android:color="@color/base_frame_border_color"
        />
</shape>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: for other backgrounds just make solid color fully transparent - #00000000 or solid.

Comment: I'm sorry my question wasn't clear, I edited it to add a better example.
Paddings didn't affect the stroke sharpness.
Setting solid color to #20000000 indeed make the stroke sharp, but it's not the color I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found what's happening and how to fix it.

It seems that Android, when filling a ShapeDrawable with a border, doesn't fill it to it's full size but just to the middle of the stroke. So, with a stroke of 2dp, it leave a space of 1dp all around. This can be noticed only when using alphaed borders, like I'm doing, because normally the border cover it.

Tho fix this behaviour, I used a LayerList drawable containing two ShapeDrawables, one for the solid color (with no borders) and one for the stroke (with no solid color):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/base_frame_solid_color"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/frame_border_size"
                android:color="@color/base_frame_border_color"
                />
            <padding
                android:left="@dimen/frame_padding_size"
                android:top="@dimen/frame_padding_size"
                android:right="@dimen/frame_padding_size"
                android:bottom="@dimen/frame_padding_size"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

It works, but being the border superimposed to the "solid" background, it's color need some adjustment.